# javafxのSampleEventHandlerのエラー

Tags: java, javafx

eclipseにて、書籍通りにコードを打つと、SampleEventHandlerの部分にエラー(型に解決できない)が出てコード通りに実行できません。なぜなのかわからないため質問しました。

```java
package lesson3;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Sample6 extends Application {
    private Label lb;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    public void start(Stage stage)throws Exception
    {

        lb = new Label("いらっしゃいませ。");

        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();

        bp.setTop(lb);

        Scene sc = new Scene(bp,300,200);

        sc.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED,new SampleEventHandler());
        sc.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED,new SampleEventHandler());

        stage.setScene(sc);

        stage.setTitle("サンプル");
        stage.show();
        class SampleEventHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent>{
            public void handle(MouseEvent e)
            {
                if(e.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED) {
                    lb.setText("いらっしゃいませ。");

                }
                else if(e.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED)
                {
                    lb.setText("ようこそ。");
                    {
                    }
                }

                // TODO 自動生成されたメソッド・スタブ

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

カッコを閉じている箇所を書籍のコードと見比べてみてください。

質問文中のコードでは、 `SampleEventHandler` クラスが `start` メソッドの中で定義されています。

```java
public class Sample6 extends Application {
    // 中略
    public void start(Stage stage)throws Exception
    {
        // 中略
        class SampleEventHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent>{
            // 中略
        }
    }
}
```

それに対し、おそらく書籍に書かれているコードでは、`start`メソッドの外で定義されていると思います。

```java
public class Sample6 extends Application {
    // 中略
    public void start(Stage stage)throws Exception
    {
        // 中略
    }

    class SampleEventHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent>{
        // 中略
    }
}
```